# Javascript library to explore bitcoin blockchain data by connecting to a local running node

Tags: blockexplorer, javascript

I need to get data of a block using the block height.

Is there a javascript library to get block data from the Bitcoin blockchain, by connecting to local running node or a 3rd party blockchain provider?

Comment: What exact data do you need from the block? Would a simple API call 
to e.g. blockchain.info be enough?

Comment: @0xb10c Specifically, I want to pull all the transactions that are included in a block. I don't want to be dependent on a third party api provider. It would be better if I could connect to the blockchain by using the js library and query the blockchain directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bitcoin tools library 
https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore-lib

Unofficial Node.js client for blockexplorer.com API
https://github.com/barto-/blockexplorer

or you can install bitcore full node and use bitcore-lib with that full node

Comment: Thanks. I'm using the [Bitcoin-Core](https://github.com/ruimarinho/bitcoin-core) library, which makes it easy to execute bitcoin-cli commands by simply formatting them to camel case.